# problem using count in trigger phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, trigger, count

[image: table tb_idrbch column lastbuy_idrbch and lastsell_idrbch]

how to record the number of column lastbuy_idrbch and lastsell_idrbch from table idrbch in my new table (test) using trigger and count function ?

Comment: The "number of" what?  Distinct values?  Latest number?  Number of rows?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.